# How to create focus change listener with data binding

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-mvvm

I am using following code for `EditText` focus change event and its working when I tap on one `EditText` to another `EditText` but fails when we tap outside the `EditText` .I have already added `focusable="true"and focusableInTouchMode="true"` but it does not work.

```
@BindingAdapter("onFocusChange")
public static void onFocusChange(EditText 
text, final View.OnFocusChangeListener 
listener) {
   text.setOnFocusChangeListener(listener);
}

public class Handler {
   public View.OnFocusChangeListener 
      getOnFocusChangeListener() {
           return new 
   View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View 
                  view, boolean isFocussed
          {
            //Hide Keyboard
           }
          };
        }
     }

 <data>
  <variable name="handler" type="Handler"/>
</data>
<EditText app:onFocusChange="@{handler.OnFocusChangeListener}"/>
```

Comment: try setting `OnFocusChangeListener` on the parent layout or outside layout and then check if it works

Comment: It did'nt worked

Answer (score 4):

It should work if you write your Handler class like this:

```
public class Handler {

    public OnFocusChangeListener onFocusChangeListener = new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean isFocused) {
            //Hide Keyboard
        }
    };

}
```

and your layout like this:

```
<layout>

    <data>
        <variable name="handler" type="Handler"/>
    </data>

    <EditText 
        ...
        app:onFocusChangeListener="@{handler.onFocusChangeListener}"
        ... />

</layout>
```

Don't forget to set the handler variable in the Fragment or Activity:

```
binding.setHandler(new Handler())
```

Comment: Its working but when I tap outside the EditText keyboard does not collapsed.One more think I have already added binding.setHandler(new Handler()) in activity

Comment: Yeah you still need to add the hide keyboard logic, which is a topic by itself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard

Comment: Already added the logic.Point is when I touch the screen outside Edittext the focus is not getting lost

Comment: Your EditText only looses focus when something else gets focused, like when touching another EditText, not when you press anywhere outside of the EditText on something that can not be focused.

Comment: Screen can be made focusable

Answer (score 0):

Above code works fine.I had not added clickable equals to true in the xml for the layout.